# mysql join/union 0 for non-existent

Tags: mysql, join, null

I'm trying to pull report data for option volumes in order to create a summary.  My query is currently this:

```
select concat(contract, ',', group_concat(traded), ',', sum(traded))
from 
(
    select contract, put_call, sum(oov+gv+pv) as traded
    from report_data
    where contract <> "AO" and date = '2013-01-30'
    group by contract, put_call
    order by contract asc, put_call asc
) temp
group by contract
```

It returns:

```
7A,9600,0,9600
BV,100,400,500
WA,0,900,900
WM,500,500
WZ,0,0
```

The reason that the last two rows are missing a number is because there are only puts for the WM, WZ contracts in the database on this day.  This is as opposed to the 7A or WA, where there are data for both puts and calls but no volume (hence the zero's).

I've been trying to join or union the table to itself in order to generate zero's where there are no puts (or calls) for a contract, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any suggestions?

====================================

Simpler:

Data:

```
Contract    Put_call    Traded    OtherData
  A           P           10        blah
  A           C           5         blah
  B           P           10        blah
  B           C           0         blah
  C           P           10        blah
```

I'd like a query to result in this:

```
A, 5, 10, 15
B, 0, 10, 10
C, 0, 10, 10
```

My query currently returns this:

```
A, 5, 10, 15
B, 0, 10, 10
C, 10, 10
```

It's missing the zero for the C contract calls because there is no data at all, as opposed to data with zero traded.

Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: Yes, of course.  I'll simplify above.

Comment: So you're looking for a `PIVOT`?

Comment: Yup, that's the term I was looking for.  It seems there's lots of documentation about this now that I know what to look for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem where you are trying to get aggregated results, even when there are no rows for the particular aggregation.

The solution is to create a driver table that contains all the combinations, and then left join the rest to this.

In this case, creating the driver table is rather easy, so the query looks like:

```
select concat(contract, ',', group_concat(coalesce(traded, 0)), ',', coalesce(sum(traded), 0))
from (select distinct contract, 'P' as put_call from report_data union all
      select distinct contract, 'C' as put_call from report_data
     ) driver left outer join
     (select contract, put_call, sum(oov+gv+pv) as traded
      from report_data
      where contract <> "AO" and date = '2013-01-30'
      group by contract, put_call
     ) temp
     on driver.contract = temp.contract and driver.put_call = temp.put_call
group by contract
```

First note:  I have not run this, so there may be syntax errors.

Second note:  I used `coalesce()` in the outer `select` statement to prevent NULL values from causing a problem.